# LinkedList tail assigned to head at the init block, why can't we append the head?

Tags: kotlin, linked-list

I am having a hard time grasping the `append()` method when trying to learn about basic LinkedList implementation:

```kotlin
class LinkedList(value : Int) {

    private var head : Node = Node()
    private var tail : Node
    private var length : Int = 0

    init {
        head.value = value
        tail = head
        length++
    }


    fun append(value: Int): LinkedList {
        val newNode = Node(value)
        tail.next = newNode
        tail = newNode
        length++
        return this
    }
    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "LinkedList {\nhead: $head,\ntail: $tail,\nlength: $length }"
    }

    class Node(var value : Int = -1, var next : Node? = null) {

        override fun toString(): String {
            return "Node { value: $value next: $next }"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in my implementation, when using the `append()` method we assign `tail.next` to the `newNode` that we created. The thing is that `tail.next` is `head.next`, since at the init block we initialized `tail = head`, therefore I can't understand why in the `append()` method we can't do `head.next = newNode` instead of `tail.next = newNode`.

Technically I know what would happen - we would not advance any further than one time and just rewrite the same node over and over, but I am finding it really hard to understand why since at the `init { }` block we declared `tail` to point to the same address in memory that `head` is, therefore anyway what we are doing is advancing the `head.next` over and over, so why not use it in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The thing is that `tail.next` is `head.next`, since at the init block we initialized `tail = head`, therefore I can't understand why in the `append()` method we can't do `head.next = newNode` instead of `tail.next = newNode`.

Your proposal would work the first time it executes, but as the next statement moves `tail` to reference the new node by doing `tail = newNode`, the equivalence of `head` and `tail` no longer holds. And so if `append()` is called again, `head.next` should no longer be touched.

It may help to visualise this. Let's say we start in a scenario where we have a list `myLinkedList`, and it has already one node:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ──────────┐
│ head: ────────┐ │
│ length: 1  │  │ │
└────────────┘  │ │
                ▼ ▼
           ┌────────────┐ 
           │ value: 1   │
           │ next: null │
           └────────────┘
```

As you correctly indicate, `head == tail` at this stage. So now, we call `append(2)`. The first action is calling the `Node` constructor and assigning that reference to the local variable `newNode`:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ──────────┐
│ head: ────────┐ │
│ length: 1  │  │ │
└────────────┘  │ │                newNode
                ▼ ▼                   ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │
           │ next: null │    │ next: null │
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

Then `tail.next = newNode` is executed, which indeed has the same result as doing `head.next = newNode`:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ──────────┐
│ head: ────────┐ │
│ length: 1  │  │ │
└────────────┘  │ │                newNode
                ▼ ▼                   ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │
           │ next: ─────────│ next: null │
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

But then we do `tail = newNode`, which makes `tail` different from `head`:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ───────────────────────┐
│ head: ────────┐              │
│ length: 2  │  │              │
└────────────┘  │              │    newNode
                ▼              ▼      ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │
           │ next: ─────────│ next: null │
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

The length is also updated (above). It is clear that on a next execution of `append()`, we want the `next` member of the *second* node to be updated, not of the first node, and so it must be `tail.next` that gets assigned the new node's reference. Let's say we call `append(3)`, then after we have created a new node and assigned it to `newNode` we get this:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ───────────────────────┐
│ head: ────────┐              │
│ length: 2  │  │              │
└────────────┘  │              │                     newNode
                ▼              ▼                        ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │    │ value: 2   │
           │ next: ─────────│ next: null │    │ next: null │
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

If now we would do `head.next = newNode` we would not get the desired effect:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ───────────────────────┐
│ head: ────────┐              │
│ length: 2  │  │              │
└────────────┘  │              │                     newNode
                ▼              ▼                        ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │    │ value: 3   │
           │ next: ────────┐ │ next: null │ ┌─│ next: null │
           └────────────┘  │ └────────────┘ │  └────────────┘
                           └────────────────┘ (Wrong!)
```

This is wrong. That `next` reference in the first node should not have changed. Instead, we want the tail node to get its `next` reference updated from `null` to `newNode`:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ───────────────────────┐
│ head: ────────┐              │
│ length: 2  │  │              │
└────────────┘  │              │                     newNode
                ▼              ▼                        ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │    │ value: 3   │
           │ next: ─────────│ next: ─────────│ next: null │
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

And now finally, the `tail` reference will be updated to point to the new node that is now really the tail. And the length updates as well:

```
 myLinkedList
 ↓
┌────────────┐ 
│ tail: ─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ head: ────────┐                                │
│ length: 3  │  │                                │
└────────────┘  │                                │   newNode
                ▼                                ▼      ↓
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ value: 1   │    │ value: 2   │    │ value: 3   │
           │ next: ─────────│ next: ─────────│ next: null │
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

We can now see that `head.next` should not be changed by `append` ever again. It should only happen when the *second* node is added. The common principle is that the *last* node in the list should get its `next` member updated. In one particular case that *last* node happens to be `head`, but that is just coincidence. We can better rely on updating `tail.next`, as that is guaranteed to be an update in the tail node, where `null` will be replaced with a reference to the new node.

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Okay great. But I don't understand when are at the 2nd time of using the append() method and we do tail.next = newNode, how does the pointer of `tail` always keep up with the last `next` value of `head`?

Comment: I added some visualisations. Let me know if you need me to extend that with what happens in a subsequent call of `append`.

Comment: Thanks, just saw your edit - can you indeed expand on what happens in a subsequent call of append?

Comment: OK, updated it.

Comment: One of the best answers I ever got in StackOverflow. Thanks a lot, everything is now clear :) hopefully you can vote this one up for future people getting stuck in understanding this concept

Answer (score 1):

`tail` is the same as `head` only *initially*. After a call of `append`, `tail` is set to the new node, here,

```
tail = newNode
```

which is not `head` anymore.

If you replace `tail.next = newNode` with `head.next = newNode`, the first time you call `append`, it will work as expected, because `head` and tail are the same. But after that, `tail` points to the newly inserted node, and `head` doesn't change.

```
[ node ] -> [ node ]
  ^^^^        ^^^^
  head        tail
```

A subsequent `append` would change `head.next` to the new node, so you would end up with `head` pointing to a node, which is linked to another node, and `tail` pointing to a third node that is not linked to the former two.

```
     ----------------------|
    |                      V
[ node ]    [ node ]   [ node ]
  ^^^^        ^^^^       
  head        tail
```

That's not what you want, is it?

You can, however, do `head.next = newNode`, and also do `head = newNode`. That is equivalent to renaming `tail` to `head` and `head` to `tail` at the same time.

Comment: Understood to the fullest by trincot answer. Hopefully you can vote this one up for future people getting stuck in understanding this concept